# Is there a way to achieve postgres table partitioning using gorm v2?

Tags: go, go-gorm, golang-migrate

In gorm v2 https://gorm.io/docs/index.html, is there any way to specify that this table is partitioned by some column like https://pg.uptrace.dev/table-partitioning/?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is called sharding in gorm:

- https://gorm.io/docs/sharding.html
- https://github.com/go-gorm/sharding#sharding-process

Comment: Thanks for sharing the document link. But I think it is slightly different than what I am looking for.

In postgres partitioning, we can query parent table and it will query respective partitions internally but in sharding we need to specify the partition key and to fetch all data we need to write everything manually.